# sam init --runtime nodejs14.19 is not working

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

When I try to create SAM Application with runtime nodejs. It is throwing an Invalid value of runtime

Command that I'm running:

```
sam init --runtime nodejs14.19 --name helloworld
```

Error:

```
Usage: sam init [OPTIONS]
Try 'sam init -h' for help.

Error: Invalid value for '-r' / '--runtime': invalid choice: nodejs14.19. (choose from dotnet6, dotnet5.0, dotnetcore3.1, go1.x, java11, java8.al2, java8, nodejs16.x, nodejs14.x, nodejs12.x, provided, provided.al2, python3.9, python3.8, python3.7, python3.6, ruby2.7)
```